# Site Columns and Content Type missing

Tags: 2007, site-collection, content-database

My task is the create a replication of a live site collection on a pre production server after the move none of the site collection Content type or site columns are listed.

So far I have copied the content database of the live site manually into the pre production sql server

I created a site collection by running this command

`stsadm -o createsiteinnewdb -url http://domain/sites/collection -owneremail m.user@fake.com -ownerlogin fake\user_m -sitetemplate sts -title “Site Name” -databaseserver "SQLSERVER" -databasename “Intranet_TempDelete”`

Then I deleted the database "Intranet_TempDelete"

And ran the command to attach the copied database

```
stsadm.exe -O addcontentdb -url http://domain/sites/collection -databasename WSS_Content_Collection
```

Is there a way to retreive these content type and columns?

Comment: I opened sharepoint manager 2007 and can see the all content types listed, they must not be associated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a new site column and got this error

The directory is not a subdirectory of the root directory. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070090)

I searched around and it was suggested that an IISRESET helps resolve this error.

I ran "iisreset" and the content types and site columns are now populated.